# Images load fine locally, but not on webserver

Tags: html, css, image

been looking around here for a bit but still haven't found an answer.

Have an issue with a site I'm working on. Site is entirely self contained in a folder. Trying to reference one image for a parallax section on the website. Referenced like this in the main css file:

```
#services {
background-image: url("../images/dark.JPG");}
```

Main css file is located in maindir/css. Image that I'm looking for is located in maindir/images/.

It worked locally, so I tried to upload the entire folder to my testing domain. However, when I load up the site, this one specific image doesn't come up. I can confirm in FileZilla that the file uploaded without a problem, and can download and confirm that the file's intact. Other images load without a problem, but trying to replace this specific image with any other image yields the same results.

Is this something I may be doing wrong or potentially an issue with my webhost? Going through Lunarpages and have had a few random buggy incidents like this before, but I wanted to figure out if it was my own ineptitude to begin with haha. Again, nothing is stored anywhere on the computer - all local to the folder the rest of the site is in.

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue? If you inspect the element using your browser's dev tools - what url is it trying to use for the image?

Comment: Capitalisation issue?

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: What webserver do you use? What is the url: subfolder or root?

Comment: I second Aric Watson, I've encountered many instances where permissions prevented the image from loading. Here's how you can make sure this is the issue, try typing the full URL to the image in your browser (eg: http://yourdomain.com/images/dark.jpg, if you get a 'forbidden' notice, there's your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I figured in my comment, it's a capitalisation issue. On your local machine, where the file system is case insensitive, it's no problem to use "JPG" to access a file ending in "jpg". However, on the Apache server, case does matter.

[`http://nearsighted.ninja/images/dark.jpg`](http://nearsighted.ninja/images/dark.jpg) loads
[`http://nearsighted.ninja/images/dark.JPG`](http://nearsighted.ninja/images/dark.JPG) does not load!

Solution: write the filename in your css exactly as it is, with lowercase "jpg". (Or, rename the file.)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably developing on a Windows machine, and deploying on a Linux machine. Windows file system is case insensitive, so .jpg and .JPG and .Jpg are all the same.

On Linux, where you're deploying, the file system is usually case-sensitive. Which means xxx.jpg and xxx.JPG are interpreted to be different files.

It's always better to use the same environment for both development and deployment. You can install a virtual machine for testing your work locally.